# mpiexec fails as MPI init aborts

Tags: mpich

I am trying to install [MPICH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPICH) 2 on a 64-bit machine running on Ubuntu 11.04 (Natty Narwhal). I used

```
sudo apt-get install mpich2
```

First I was surprised to see that mpd was not installed. On looking up on Google, I saw that [Hydra](http://www.auroraux.org/index.php/Hydra_Package_Manager) is the new default package manager. 
So I tried to run my MPI code. I got the following error.

```
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [ip-10-99-75-58:02212] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A
> system-required executable either could not be found or was not
> executable by this user in file
> ../../../../../../orte/mca/ess/singleton/ess_singleton_module.c at
> line 357 [ip-10-99-75-58:02212] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A
> system-required executable either could not be found or was not
> executable by this user in file
> ../../../../../../orte/mca/ess/singleton/ess_singleton_module.c at
> line 230 [ip-10-99-75-58:02212] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A
> system-required executable either could not be found or was not
> executable by this user in file ../../../orte/runtime/orte_init.c at
> line 132
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process
> is likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process
> can fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
> environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
> here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
> Open MPI developer):
> 
>   orte_ess_set_name failed   --> Returned value A system-required
> executable either could not be found or was not executable by this
> user (-127) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process
> is likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process
> can fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or
> environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
> here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
> Open MPI developer):
> 
>   ompi_mpi_init: orte_init failed   --> Returned "A system-required
> executable either could not be found or was not executable by this
> user" (-127) instead of "Success" (0)
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------
> *** The MPI_Init() function was called before MPI_INIT was invoked.
> *** This is disallowed by the MPI standard.
> *** Your MPI job will now abort.
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

First of all, it looks to me as an [Open MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_MPI) error. But I installed MPICH 2 and not Open MPI.

Secondly, I am at a fix on how to handle this as all help seems to be directed to Open MPI users. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04. I find my problem is because I have both open-mpi and mpich2 on my computer. When I compile my program using mpicc, it will be linked to open-mpi not mpich2. To fix this problem, you can use "mpicc.mpich2" to compile your program and then use "mpiexec.mpich2" to execute your code.

Comment: Fixed for me. Also, you have a typo, should be: `mpiexec.mpich2` . Thanks!

Comment: I use `mpiexec.mpich` run the code.`mpicc.mpich2 hello.c -o h` `mpiexec.mpich -np <num> ./h`

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, these error messages are all Open MPI errors.  For some reason, you appear to also have a (badly configured?) copy of Open MPI installed somewhere.  You can check which particular file you are executing when you type `mpiexec` by running `which mpiexec`.  I believe that you can compare this with the result of:

`dpkg --listfiles mpich2`

(or similar) in order to figure out where the MPICH2 package was installed.

Comment: Hi Dave. Thanks for the response. However, i get the same error even if i explicitly use the mpiexec executable i get by compiling mpich2 from source. Does mpich use some openmpi libraries internally ?.

Comment: No, MPICH2 does not use any Open MPI libraries or executables whatsoever.  Make sure that you are also using the `mpicc` (or similar) wrapper script that came with MPICH2 when building your application.  The message you are seeing indicates that you built your application with Open MPI's `mpicc`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me, and I found the issue.  Somewhere on your system during startup LD_PRELOAD was set to point to libmpi.so in OpenMPI.

Example:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=<some_directory>/openmpi/1.4.4/lib/libmpi.so
```

The result is that MPICH2 fails.  Just do 'unset LD_PRELOAD' before running MPICH2 and the issue goes away.

Note that setting LD_PRELOAD to OpenMPI's libmpi.so is actually required sometimes for OpenMPI to work, so unsetting may break OpenMPI for you.  Just remember to reset it if you need to use OpenMPI.