# Trouble using mpirun from mpich2 after compiling using CMake

Tags: linux, cmake, mpi

I am having trouble trying to run MPI . I installed mpich2-1.4.1p1, and when I run the mpi program using mpirun, I get:

```
[starsky:27711] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A system-required executable either could not be found or was not executable by this user in file ../../../../../../orte/mca/ess/singleton/ess_singleton_module.c at line 357
[starsky:27711] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A system-required executable either could not be found or was not executable by this user in file ../../../../../../orte/mca/ess/singleton/ess_singleton_module.c at line 230
[starsky:27711] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A system-required executable either could not be found or was not executable by this user in file ../../../orte/runtime/orte_init.c at line 132
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like orte_init failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during orte_init; some of which are due to configuration or
environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure;
here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an
Open MPI developer):

  orte_ess_set_name failed
  --> Returned value A system-required executable either could not be found or was not executable by this user (-127) instead of ORTE_SUCCESS
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[starsky:27719] [[INVALID],INVALID] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: A system-required executable either could not be found or was not executable by this user in file ../../../../../../orte/mca/ess/singleton/ess_singleton_module.c at line 357
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_mpi_init: orte_init failed
  --> Returned "A system-required executable either could not be found or was not executable by this user" (-127) instead of "Success" (0)
```

along with other very similar error messages.

This is pretty similar to the problem in [mpiexec fails as MPI init aborts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7011519/mpiexec-fails-as-mpi-init-aborts) , as I seem to have both Open MPI and mpich2 . However, I am using cmake to compile, and when I do the suggested mpicc-vt.mpich2 (mpicc-vt because I am using vampir trace) to compile, and then mpirun.mpich2 to run, I get the following error:

```
To run 'mpirun.mpich2' please ask your administrator to install the package 'mpich2'
```

I have already installed the mpich2 though. Is there a configuration that I was suppose to install the mpich2 with? When I looked at [this manual](ftp://ftp.mcs.anl.gov/pub/mpi/mpich2-doc-install.pdf) at the configurations, none seem to match what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to tell what's going on here since you have two MPI libraries installed on your system in various states of completion. I think the best thing to do at this point is to uninstall both Open MPI and MPICH and go to whichever package manager you're using and reinstall. That's the simplest way to get everything to work.

If you want the latest version (which is usually a good thing), you'll have to go directly to the source so take a look at the README that comes bundled with the tarball that you download. In general, for both of these packages, you use the standard method of installing Unix software.

```
./configure --prefix=<path for installation>
make
make install
```

There's lots of customization options for both MPICH and Open MPI that you can read about if you do a `./configure --help` and go through the README, but none of that is usually required unless you have a special system.